# Can I compile a C program on one version of Windows and then run it on another version of Windows?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, compilation, compatibility

If I compile a C program on Windows 10, can that program run on Windows 7?

If I compile a C program on Windows 10 Home, can that program run on Windows 10 Pro?

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a vote-to-close for being "About general computing hardware and software".  It's specifically asking if a program compiled under Windows 10 (Home?) can run under Windows 7 or Windows 10 Pro.  It's not about "general computing hardware and software" at all. It's actually a question that can be answered pretty specifically by someone with detailed knowledge on how to compile on Windows for an earlier version.  It's also a pretty good question that someone who doesn't already know how to correctly search for answers to would have a very hard time researching.

Comment: It depends on what your program is and how you compile and link it.

Comment: It depends greatly on what libraries you use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes , you can run your program in any windows.I think knowing about [compile process](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-does-a-c-program-executes/) can help you.

Comment: A blunt statement that's incorrect. I'm entirely sure that you cannot compile a UWP application on Windows 10 and run it on Windows 7, for example.

Answer (score -1):

You don't compile with Windows, you compile with a compiler. Where the resulting executable is able to run depends on the compiler, not which OS the compiler runs on.

Comment: It also depends on the run-time libraries the compiled binary is linked against.